# Typescript doesn't manage to infer type from derived generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, rtk-query

I'm trying to use my custom api client in RTK (Redux Toolkit Query) but i'm facing typescript errors

Given the implementation below:

```
/**
 * Class used to abstract calls to user API
 */
class UserClient {
    // ... other client methods

    login(email: string, pwd: string) {
        // axios.post(...)
    }

    getUser() {
        // axios.get(...)
    }
}

type UserBaseQuery<TMethod extends keyof UserClient> = (p: {
    method: TMethod
    params: Parameters<UserClient[TMethod]>
}) => any

/**
 * Base Query for RTK
 */
const userBaseQuery: UserBaseQuery<keyof UserClient> = async ({ method, params }) => {
    try {
        const _client = new UserClient()
        const result = await _client[method](...params) // error here
        return { data: result }
    } catch (axiosError) {
        return axiosError
    }
}
```

[typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUhhAbAhgZ2ZArsgpgE0gFwHtJEAjZfAJ0QGN9IbF540iNtLIBBABQEkoIYOBpJUkAKocEASywA7egG8okNfEIBzGfIAUWALaIZ8AFyQKlHZoA0kAA4B3HOcvWAlJCWQAvqvVahOj4up7efn7g+ACe9liSHABCKFgAiuhYlNEAPAAqALJY+AAWhHhYAB74CjhoANZY0YQAZgmZsgr4AHyQALyQuvbmKmpqBkWlLpAFE2X+DojUBsjmPIuI49WUyNlS7fByigDaMyVlALpd4D6evT2I8tHg4KAQ0JDJ2JDpmdGQzYROAAlXIAaUEwhohHkFHYmU+aQyWXMe0oCJ+WWyDSarVRHUUPX6KGi8hoA28m0mdns62WvluPRGoyofyZo1GUJh9AA+qJDvR+vIsI42pR8SF3PN2ZzYZQsMh0PABSRHMYeXzOkdKRddAA6fU0pbITzAYCQTKUQGQYqZLBS0Zy-DoSjyLyQHCIfCIcxyhVK3zzHwMT00YoDRAVGSEZAAUUolsoYXtakdztdEajsfjgMD1yAA)

I would like Typescript to automatically infer `params`' type according to `method` field, (e.g: if method === 'login', then 'params' should be of type [string, string]

Unfortunately it seems not to be working and in addition to that, I get this error:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

[typescript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3UL6.png)

---

Doing this works well but unfortunately it is not generic enough to be usable in my use case (RTK):

```
const userBaseQuery: UserBaseQuery<'login'> = async ({ method, params }) => {
    try {
        const _client = new UserClient()
        const result = await _client[method](...params) // error here
        return { data: result }
    } catch (axiosError) {
        return axiosError
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is shown in the ts playground but here is it as test:
`A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter`

Comment: In future, please use the "edit" link, not comments, to improve the question. I've done it for you this time. (And note that some sites are blocked for some people, hence the need for your question to be complete **here**, rather than relying on people seeing things off-site.)

Comment: Looks like you're running into [#35801](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)?